# Llamar una función con evento en JQuery

Tags: jquery, eventos

Tengo una función que cuando cambia el select se dispara y entonces llama otra función que ya tiene un evento y hace sus cosas. Quiero que la función llamada por en la función change del seleccionar, que hasta ahora si utilizabas el evento `evento_nuevo` enviaba que era `undefined`, identifique que ahora no es undefined sino que es 15. Realmente me da igual que envie o no una variable, lo hago porque supongo que es más fácil, pero si simplemente puede identificar que la que llama ahora es la función con el evento nuevo seria perfecto.

```
$('.seleccionador').change(function(){ 
   var evento_nuevo = "15";
    funcion_prueba(evento_nuevo);


});

funcion_prueba(evento_externo, evento_nuevo){

   if{
     if(evento_nuevo != "undefined"){
        //haz cosas
      }
     else{
      //otras
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba algo como esto :)

```
<script>
$('.seleccionador').change(function(){ 
    funcion_prueba("",15);
});

funcion_prueba(evento_externo, evento_nuevo){
    console.log(evento_externo, evento_nuevo);
    if(evento_nuevo != "undefined"){
        alert("No existe");
    }else{
        alert("Existe "+evento_nuevo);
    }
}
</script>
```

Básicamente le estoy diciendo que cuando cambie el `select` mande al `change` llamar la función con sus dos parametros que recibe, solo que como `evento_externo` no se utiliza lo dejo en blanco

Saludos :)